# How to decode a property with type of JSON dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I am currently getting the following error in my tests:

[image]

If I correctly understood the problem, then I need to convert my dictionary to decoder.

At the moment i have the next code:

```
static var validConfirmAuthorizationData: [String: Any] { return json("valid_confirm_authorization_data") }
```

Which has the following structure:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "success": true
    }
}
```

And the response class itself which I use together with the decodable:

```
public struct SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse: Decodable {
    public let id: String
    public let success: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }

    enum DataCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case success
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let dataContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DataCodingKeys.self, forKey: .data)
        id = try dataContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        success = try dataContainer.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
    }
}
```

---

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry but I didn't see anything about `JSONDecoder` in the article.
As I understood I should write something like this:
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
try decoder.decode(???.self, from: fixture)
but it is not clear what to use instead ???. self since I have JSON, it's just a string and not a class of some model

Comment: You have a Dictionary? Add a method for `SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse` `init(dictionary: [String: Any])`?

Comment: @Larme no, i have only ```public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {``` I threw off the sample code in the question

Comment: I would have done: `extension SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse { init?(dict: [String: Any] { guard let id = dict["id"] as? String, let success: dict["success"] as? Bool else { return nil }; self.id = id; self.success = success} }`, and `let response = SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse(dict: fixture)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to solve the problem as follows.

First of all, I created `SpecDecodableModel`:

```
public struct SpecDecodableModel<T: Decodable> {
    static func create(from fixture: [String: Any]) -> T {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategyFormatters = [DateUtils.dateFormatter, DateUtils.ymdDateFormatter]
        let fixtureData = Data(fixture.jsonString!.utf8)
        return try! decoder.decode(T.self, from: fixtureData)
    }
}
```

After that, I can convert my `JSON` structures to the desired type.

And now returning to the original problem, I can fix it as follows:

```
let fixture = DataFixtures.validConfirmAuthorizationData
let response = SpecDecodableModel<SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse>.create(from: fixture)
```

**Update**:

```
public extension Dictionary {

    var jsonString: String? {
        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: []),
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            return string
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer, `Dictionary` doesn't have a property `jsonString`. This must be something you have added yourself or from some 3rd party library, so please explain what it is.

Comment: I had a problem with the fact that I could not use my fixtures as a parameter for SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse since it implemented decodable.
So I wrote a SpecDecodableModel that, using JSONDecoder, allows you to decode from JSON strings (my fixture) for my decodable class.

Comment: This doesn't clarify your answer and you should not try to do that in a comment anyway. Please update your answer by explaining what `jsonString` is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options, you could create a codable struct with a variable named data. Data would have the type SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse. Then you would decode into the new struct.

You could decode into a dictionary like:

```swift
let decoded = JsonDecoder().decode([String: SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse].self, from: someData)

let response = decoded[“data”]
```

Or you could write a custom decoder which I usually try to avoid.

Comment: I can't write smth like this, because i get the next error: "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'"

Answer (score 0):

```
public struct AuthorizationData: Codable {
    public let id: String
    public let success: Bool
    
    init(id: String, success: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.success = success
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case success
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(success, forKey: .success)
    }
}

public struct SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse: Codable {
    public let data: AuthorizationData
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        data = try container.decode(AuthorizationData.self, forKey: .data)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(data, forKey: .data)
    }
    
    init(_ data: AuthorizationData) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

func authData() -> Data? {
    let authorizationData = AuthorizationData(id: "1", success: true)
    let response = SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse(authorizationData)
    
    guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(response) else {
        return nil
    }
    if let jsonString = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("jsonString", jsonString)
    }
    return prettyJsonData
}

func authResponse() {
    if let data = authData() {
        guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SEConfirmAuthorizationResponse.self, from: data) else {
            return
        }
        print("response", response)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.